# PL/SQL Oracle DBMS_JOB/DBMS_SCHEDULER passing parameters

Tags: asynchronous, parameters, plsql

How do I pass parameters to DBMS_JOB/SCHEDULER async call. I have long running PL/SQL procedure, which takes few parameters, including SQL table of integers (ids). How do I create procedure which calls this PL/SQL long running procedure asynchronosly and passes parameters to it?

```
PROCEDURE "RUN_ARCHIVING_SEARCH"
(
    a_arch_rule_code_id_list IN INLISTNUMBERS,
    a_lang IN VARCHAR2,
    a_session_id IN NUMBER
)
```

Thnx,
Beef

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a *program* whose `program_type` is `'STORED_PROCEDURE'`, try creating *jobs* where each job's `job_type` is `'PLSQL_BLOCK'`. This way, your `job_action` is actually the PL/SQL block necessary to call your stored procedure with the appropriate arguments. You could theoretically fabricate the PL/SQL block on-the-fly with the code necessary to re-create `a_arch_rule_code_id`.

Comment: @0xDEAD BEEF: What I'm saying is that you could write the .NET code necessary to construct a PL/SQL block from scratch. Your .NET code would write that PL/SQL block in such a way that the PL/SQL code re-constructs `a_arch_rule_code_id_list`. For example, your .NET code could emit this PL/SQL block: `DECLARE list ...; BEGIN list(0) := 1; list(1) := 2; RUN_ARCHIVING_SEARCH(list, ...); END;`

Comment: That is uggly solution. I had this one in my mind, but I was really hoping for nicer solution.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the maximum number of numbers you might need to pass to the procedure, you're probably better off storing the numbers in a table, then the job will query the table to get the numbers to process.

Comment: Is there a way to squeeze/unsqueeze all data in xml?

Comment: In my experience, translating data into xml tends to increase the volume of data, rather than reduce it...